# Return range (real) dimensions following DELETE action (clear contents only) in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm writing a script in Google Sheets that will register the email and timestamp of the latest modification made on a pre-determined column (only this column will be made available for editing). For that I'm using `onEdit()` trigger. The script will get the active range, get `rowStart` and `rowEnd` and write in the adjacent cells email and timestamp. I've already handled input data. However, I'm struggling to manipulate the "DELETE" action in a range with multiple rows, since `e.range` returns only one row following a "clear contents" method.

I want my script to be able to identify how many cells have been selected before a DELETE press (clear contents) and to write email and timestamp on adjacent cells just like it does for entered values (copy / paste operation).

An example:

There are 4 rows (say C2, C3, C4 and C5) with a "YES" stamp in column C, email of current user in column D and timestamp in column E. I select the last 3 (C3, C4 and C5) and press DELETE. With my script, only cells D3 and E3 are filled with email and date/time since e.range returns range as if it contained only one cell as opposed to 3.

This is the script

```
function onEdit(e) {
    // Prevent changes in columns different than the used one.
    if (e.range.getColumn() != 3) return;

    for (var i = e.range.rowStart; i <= e.range.rowEnd ; i++) {
      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 4).setValue(e.user.getEmail());

      e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(i, 5).setValue(new Date());
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note that simple triggers have restrictions about identity access, so you might not be able to do what you wish. You may perhaps refer to other `Sheet` / `Range` methods to detect the selection or the number of rows.

Comment: In fact, enabled users necessarily have a Google account. His / her email will be logged accordingly.

Comment: I am well aware that editors must have Google Accounts. But, you still are not guaranteed that you can access their email from a simple trigger. Review the Apps Script `Session` class.